# Measuring curve "closeness" with unequal data ranges

Tags: classification, curve-fitting

Provided that I have a similar example:[image: example]

where the blue data is my calculated/measured data and my red data is the given groundtruth data. The task is to get the similarity/closeness between the data and each of the given curves so that a classification can be done, it could also be possible to choose multiple classes if the results seem to be very close.

I can divide the problem in my mind to several subproblems:

1. The data range is no the same
2. The resolution of the calculated/measured data is higher than the groundtruth data
3. The calculated data has some bias/shift

The following questions come to my mind when trying to solve those problems

- Is it better to fit the calculated/measured data first then attempting to solve the problem?
- Would it be fine to use the data points as is and calculate the mean squared error of each curve assuming it is a fitting attempt and thus getting the best fit? What would be the effect of the bias/shift in this case?
- What is a good approach to dealing with the data/range mismatch, by decreasing the number of samples for the higher sampled version or increasing the number of samples for the lower sampled data in the given range?

Comment: Fit a model to the ground truth data (i.e. each of the two red curves). Given new data (i.e. blue points), evaluate each model at the new $x$ values, to obtain predicted $y$ values. Compare these predictions to the actual new $y$ values (e.g. using squared error).

Comment: @user20160 That is an interesting approach, I will try it out. Thank you.